# Is there any way to capture the POST response from network traffic using selenium webdriver java?

Tags: java, maven, selenium-webdriver, post, network-traffic

Actually I am using a web browser where I need to send a form page. And internally a post request is send and generates a response. Is there any way to capture POST response without sending request data in selenium using java? I am using maven project.

I have tried all the possible that fetched from internet but in vain.